# Exporting feature attributes and coordinates to CSV with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, csv

I've retrieved some attributes and coordinates from a point layer in QGIS:

```py
path_file = myfile
layer = QgsVectorLayer(path_file, "name", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
features = layer.getFeatures()
for f in features:
    point = f.geometry().asPoint()
    x = point.x()
    y = point.y()
```

and I'd like to export `"ID"`, `"x"`, and `"y"` values into a CSV file, possibly one for a column. I tried with `.write()` but couldn't get a good output. Any help?

Comment: there is no sign of you writing the variables out in your code example

Comment: @IanTurton, I've used the code just to print the values on screen with `print("ID: %d; XY coordinates: %f, %f" % (f['ID'], x, y))`, but maybe I didn' get the point of your comment

Comment: Well try printing to a file instead of the screen, not sure I see your problem

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking for, actually. A formatted .csv with a column for every value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this script:

```
import csv

path_file = myfile
csv_file_path = 'path/to/csv_file.csv'

layer = QgsVectorLayer(path_file, "name", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

# open the file in the write mode
csv_file = open(csv_file_path, 'w')
# create the csv writer
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

features = iface.activeLayer().getFeatures()
for f in features:
    point = f.geometry().asPoint()
    x = point.x()
    y = point.y()
    # write a row to the csv file
    writer.writerow([f["ID"], x, y])

# close the file
csv_file.close()
```